# how to change default python version of container at docker?

Tags: python-3.x, docker, docker-compose

I installed docker on background of python 3.7 and built container and image, which is /c/Users/conkj/sample:/sample mlearn:init /bin/bash

To run tensorflow, i had to install python 3.6. After i installed python 3.6, at the first page of docker, if i checked version of python, it shown python 3.6. But at the container, as "docker run -it -v /c/Users/conkj/sample:/sample mlearn:init /bin/bash", it shown python 3.7. I'd tried "pip install python 3.6" and built other images and containers.(Maybe it wasn't right way to build.) But still stuck in...

Could you guys give me solutions for changing python 3.7 to 3.6 at docker container?

Comment: Docker container environment is not tied to your PC one. Please, check what Python version is used inside your Dockerfile. How did you built your image?

Comment: @RomanKotov this's way i built image : 1) docker pull continuumio/miniconda3 2) docker ps -a 3) docker commit <container ID> mlearn:init 4)  docker run -it -v /path mlearn:init /bin/bash

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should use a proper basic image for your container, like:

`docker run -it --rm  python:3.6 bash`

`docker run -it --rm  python:3.6-alpine sh`

Look for other available tags [here](https://hub.docker.com/r/library/python/tags/)